# Sublime editor: How to complete with exactly previous/next match via shortcuts like vi does (CTRL+p, CTRL+n)?

Tags: autocomplete, match, sublimetext2, vi

In vi there is a very helpfull option, which allows you to complete with the previous match by pressing ctrl+p (or n for next match)

for instance, take the following code

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE_1");
while(list($a, $b) = mysql_fetch_row($res){
  // do something
}

$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE_2");
while(list($a, $b) = mysql_f
```

lets assume that the cursor is next to the 'f' letter above. If you press `control+p` in vi, it completes with the `mysql_fetch_row` found above.

Is there a similar shortcut in sublime, or maybe an easy way to make a macro for it? I have no knowledge of python, so every help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I noticed in vim it brings up an auto complete menu with all available options. But are you just looking for the previous/next match?

Comment: Ideally, for every shorthand keystroke it will traverse one back (or forth). No need for menu (allthough it would be welcome!)

Comment: Creating a menu would essentially be like the normal pop up auto complete wouldn't it? Getting the previous/next match via a plugin is doable. I threw together together the following ([link](https://gist.github.com/skuroda/5105635)) which should get the previous match (once). You can tie it to a keybinding using "previous_keyword_match" as the command. Keep in mind that `control+p` (depending on your system) is a mapped default command.  I added what I was using for a test key map, though you probably will want to change it.

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you very much!!!

Could you please make it a complete answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a menu would essentially be like the normal pop up auto complete wouldn't it? Getting the previous/next match via a plugin is doable. I threw together together the following ([link](https://gist.github.com/skuroda/5105635)) which should get the previous match (once). You can tie it to a keybinding using `previous_keyword_match` as the command. Keep in mind that control+p (depending on your system) is a mapped default command. I added what I was using for a test key map, though you probably will want to change it.

Oh and just as a small configuration side note, I hard coded 5000 (which allows the search the view backwards for 5000 characters or until it reaches the start point again). If you find yourself needing more than that, feel free to adjust it. Though I don't think that is necessary since you only get a single match.

Comment: Thank you skuroda! Works almost perfectly!
Just one more little thing... it does not seem to work in variables, for example `$thisisavariable` will not be matched with `$this`+`CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+p`. I believe this is something pretty easy to be fixed...

Comment: Is it completing with another word that starts with `this`? If so, it's probably because of how the parsing of "words" is occurring. Take a look at the `word_separators` setting. You may want to create a syntax specific one that removes the `$` Keep in mind that if you do this, when you do something like double click to select the word, it will include the `$`

Comment: forgot to mention @user1238964 before. I don't know if you get notified, so trying again.

Comment: I took @skuroda's code, augmented it, and made it available as the WordCompletion plugin in Package Control. It only works with SublimeText 3. The source is [available on github](https://github.com/schmave/Sublime-Word-Completion) too.