# How to complete word like vim with Sublime Text2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a plugin which complete word where is in current directory by Sublime Text2?

I miss vim's keyword completion (Ctrl + N).

Answer (score 0):

You can autocomplete filenames with AutoFileName plugin:

https://github.com/BoundInCode/AutoFileName

Answer (score 0):

How you are describing "ctrl + n" and how someone else described it to me aren't the same, so I'm a little confused (though it could be because of a different setup in vi(m). They were asking for keyword match (ctrl + p and ctrl + n in vi). You may want to take a look.

[Sublime editor: How to complete with exactly previous/next match via shortcuts like vi does (CTRL+p, CTRL+n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260843/sublime-editor-how-to-complete-with-exactly-previous-next-match-via-shortcuts-l/15279304#15279304)

I expanded my gist to also move forward, though as I stated there, it only inserts the first match.